# Expo Firebase Authentication "While trying to resolve module `idb` from file"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

This is my first app. I'm trying to use Firebase for Email/Password authentication. I followed the basic tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#web-version-9, and I keep getting this error:

```
While trying to resolve module `idb` from file '.../node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js', the package `/Users/##/##/##/node_modules/idb/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/##/##/##/node_modules/idb/build/index.cjs`.
```

I've added this to metro.config.js:

```
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs'],
  },
```

and the issue is still there.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue ["firebase": "^9.7.0", "react-native": "0.68.1","expo": "^45.0.0"]

Comment: I have the same error too. "expo: ~45.0.0", "firebase: ^9.8.1"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To resolve this issue, create a **metro.config.js** file in the project root. In the file add the file extension `cjs`. [details](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/#adding-more-file-extensions-to--assetexts)

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("cjs");

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THSr4.png)

Comment: Great answer! Worked for me

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me as well!

Comment: ty, all else failed.

Comment: @polar Are you using expo? After config metro, You can clear the cache by `expo start --android --clear` or try to delete node_modules and reinstall packages. It should work.

Answer (score 6):

I get the same error when adding firebase to a clean project. I think there's something funny with the latest firebase version so I've downgraded to 9.6.11 to temporarily fix the problem. Hopefully they sort it out soon...

```
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@9.6.11
```